# Conditional in Ansible

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I am writing a playbook in Ansible which configures network devices from a file. When the playbook is started, the contents of the configuration file will be displayed on screen. I will have a prompt appear and if the user enters 'y' then the next tasks will continue, otherwise i want the playbook execution to stop.

I have not found a good example online for this which uses the 'when' statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to achieve this.
The prompt can be done either with [`vars_prompt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) or with [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html), although `pause` would be more convenient if you indeed want to display something before asking an user input.
While ending the playbook can either be done with [`meta`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) or [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html).

Here is one example of playbook achieving this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: Is the configuration ok? [y/N]
      register: configuration

    - name: End the play if the user didn't answer `y`
      meta: end_play 
      when: configuration.user_input != 'y'

    - debug:
        msg: Do the configuration here
```

This yields:

- When answered `y`

  ```
  PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

  TASK [pause] *****************************************************************************************************
  [pause]
  Is the configuration ok? [y/N]:
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": "Do the configuration here"
  }

  PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- When answered something else than `y` — which I assume here to be the default, as pointed by the `N` in capital in the choice list `[y/N]`

  ```
  PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

  TASK [pause] *****************************************************************************************************
  [pause]
  Is the configuration ok? [y/N]:
  ok: [localhost]

  PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```